# How to listen to Boot Complete broadcast in Oneplus?

Tags: android

I am working on an android application that listens to Boot Complete Broadcast and performs some processes.
This broadcast works on my Moto G5 and simulator, however, on Oneplus the application never receives it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **BroadCastReciver** class like this :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RebootService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Service is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Define your service in `AndroidManifest`.

```
<receiver android:name=".RebootService">

    <intent-filter>


        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

And finally :

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: This is correct way however, it doesn't work on OnePlus

Comment: did you enable this property : android:exported="true" ?

Comment: Yes I did. These are the properties which I have in the manifest : android:directBootAware="true" | android:enabled="true" | android:exported="true"